# I can't subscribe publishSubject from embed view controller in swift

Tags: rx-swift

I have MainViewController that contains ContainerView.
and ContainerView have embeded segue that indicate ThirdViewController

In ThirdViewController, I create PublishSubject, If I select something in PickerView then emit the value into PublishSubject.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMh9d.jpg)

then MainViewController subscribe PublishSubject from ThirdViewController.

so if this success , in MainViewController I will get value from PickerView.

But my problem is I can't get anything, even maybe can't subscribe.

what is problem??? what can I do ???

MainViewController

```
if  let thirdVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ThirdViewController") as? ThirdViewController {
                    print("third segue success")

                    thirdVC.selectFeelingSubject.subscribe(onNext : {
                        print($0)

                    }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

ThirdViewController

```
var selectFeelingSubject = PublishSubject<String>()



 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    selectFeelingSubject.onNext(feelingArray[row])

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
if  let thirdVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ThirdViewController") as? ThirdViewController {
    print("third segue success")
    thirdVC.selectFeelingSubject.subscribe(onNext : {
        print($0)
    })
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Is not giving you the view controller that is in the main view controller. It is instantiating an entirely new view controller.

You need the actual one that is in the main view controller. Try this instead:

```
let thirdVC = self.children[0] as! ThirdViewController
    thirdVC.selectFeelingSubject.subscribe(onNext : {
        print($0)
    })
    .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

If you have more than one child view controller, you will need to change the `0` to the appropriate number so you are getting the correct child.

Comment: thank you a lot ! you give me second code is very useful! , But still I can't get publishSubject by subscribe.   I can approach ThirdViewController, because I can get ThirdViewController data like stored properties. But changing data is not getting..... 

Comment: thank you thank you!!! I just backward in .subscribe. I did subscribe in @IBAction button Click.   I absolutely can't get some info by susbcribe subject in MainViewController because I did subscribe after event was happend. poor my self!    and you recommend me to use self.children. that is fine working! thank you !!!!